# Method that Takes in ArrayList removes words and returns an Acronym

Tags: java, arraylist

The `acronym()` method takes an `ArrayList<String>`, removes the boring words, and returns an acronym as a String.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("THE");
words.add("UNITED");
words.add("STATES");
words.add("OF");
words.add("AMERICA");
System.out.println(acronym(words)); // Prints "USA" (without the quotes)
```

I am suppose to write `acronym()`.  Use the boringWords array to filter out words that won’t be in the acronym (“THE”, “AND”, etc.).  Assume all Strings are in ALL CAPS to make the code easier.

```
public static String acronym(ArrayList<String> phrase) {
    String[] boringWords = { "THE", "AND", "OR", "OF", "FROM", "TO", "A", "AN" };
    ArrayList<String> wordList = (ArrayList<String>) phrase.clone(); //If you choose to use remove(), use wordList, which is a copy of the input parameter
    String acronym = ""; // Return this at the end of the method

    // First step: Remove all of the boring words.
    
    // Second step: Grab the first letters of wordList and concatenate them into
    // the acronym variable.
    
    // Third step: Return the acronym
    // YOUR CODE HERE IN RED
    
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I am trying to solve these problems, there are many and and there's some I am having problems with.

Comment: why do you create 'wordList' if you already have 'phrase'? how have you tried to solve it? In your comments you state exactly that what-to-do

Comment: the wordList is only there if you choose to do remove() but you don't need to. Without it i think it will destroy our inputs.

Comment: seeing as the input becomes irrelevant once you have the acronym, what's the problem?

Comment: I am just trying to find a way or ideas how to write this method because I am lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in Java. It might not be efficient though.

```
    public static String acronym(ArrayList<String> phrase) {
        String[] boringWords = { "THE", "AND", "OR", "OF", "FROM", "TO", "A", "AN" };
        ArrayList<String> wordList = (ArrayList<String>) phrase.clone(); //If you choose to use remove(), use wordList, which is a copy of the input parameter
        String acronym = ""; // Return this at the end of the method
        
        Boolean boring = false;
        
        for (String word : phrase) {
            boring = false;
            for (String boringWord : boringWords) {
                if (boringWord == word) {
                    boring = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!boring) {
                acronym += word.charAt(0);
            }
        }
        
        return acronym;
    }
```

Comment: The `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode.

Comment: this might work sometimes, but this may also lead to issues. You can use the primitive type boolean, you don't need to use the wrapper type, and you need to compare the Strings in the correct way: use the equals or equalsIgnoreCase method, don't use the  == operator: this will do a referential comparisation, while you want a comparisation based on value

Answer (score 0):

## Streams

For a different approach, you can use streams.

Define your inputs. You can use `List.of` to make an [unmodifiable `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) with simple literals syntax.

```java
List < String > boring = List.of( "THE" , "AND" , "OR" , "OF" , "FROM" , "TO" , "A" , "AN" );
List < String > input = List.of( "THE" , "UNITED" , "STATES" , "OF" , "AMERICA" );
```

We want to process the input as a series of objects, a stream. Do this with a call to `List#stream`.

Then we weed out the boring words passing a `Predicate` to the `Stream#filter` method.

Of the non-boring words that passed our predicate test, we want to extract the first letter. So we use `Stream#map` to transform each `String` object word of our input list. We pull the first letter by asking for the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer assigned by the Unicode Consortium to the first character in the stream. Beware of solutions using `char` primitive type — that type is now obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode and supported by Java. Instead, learn to work with individual characters as code point integers. After pulling the first code point number, we transform that back into a single-character `String` object by calling `Character.toString`.

At this point we have changed our stream of words into a stream of first-characters. We need to pull those together by calling `Stream#collect`, and passing method references to make a `StringBuilder` object for appending each of those first characters.

Finally we call `StringBuilder#toString` to retrieve our acronym as a `String` object.

Notice how this is technically a single-line of code! Streams pack quite a punch, a lot going on in very few words.

```java
String acronym =
        input
                .stream()
                .filter( word -> ! boring.contains( word ) )
                .map( word -> Character.toString( word.codePointAt( 0 ) ) )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: append , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Vh3ZZF).

> acronym = USA